# Passing navparams in tabs.ts then sending them to modals

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a problem. My app has facebook authentication and i am passing the parameters to all tab pages like this:

tabs.ts

```
homeParams={
    facebooknev: this.navParams.get('nev'),
    facebookemail: this.navParams.get('email'),
    facebookprofilkep: this.navParams.get('profilkep')

  }
```

tabs.html

```
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Hírek" tabIcon="home" [rootParams]="homeParams"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Tudásbázis" tabIcon="information-circle" [rootParams]="homeParams"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Halszámláló" tabIcon="contacts" [rootParams]="homeParams"></ion-tab>
```

However when i am on the second tab page i am trying to open a modal page and send the parameters to that page(which is not a tabpage):

```
  openFeltoltes(){
    const feltolt=this.modal.create(FogasfeltoltesPage,{data:this.homeParams});
    feltolt.present();
  }
```

Unfortunately cannot find homeParams with that code

welcome.ts (where i get the facebook parameters from login):

```
  let facebookadatok={
              nev: res.user.displayName,
              email: res.user.email,
              profilkep: res.user.photoURL
            }
            this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage,facebookadatok);
```

i can display data on any html pages which is part of the tabpage, but not on individual pages:

```
{{navParams.data.facebooknev}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it as shown below:

*tabs.ts*

```
openFeltoltes(){
    const feltolt=this.modal.create(FogasfeltoltesPage,{data:this.homeParams});
    feltolt.present();
  }
```

**Retrieve it:**

```
  let facebookadatok= = this.navParams.get('data');
```

Comment: Still cant find homeParams. If i add homeParams to the export class, it is empty ofc. On the html, i can show the value with this:{{navParams.data.facebooknev}}

Comment: Can you show the `code` of how to access it? Put that on your question area above.

Comment: added more info

Comment: unfortunately i am still stucked, how should i modify the modal.create part? :(